# How to remove open source noveau and replace it with the proprietary Nvidia driver?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 Nattu beta on my machine with GeForce 7025 card. But I'm falling back to classic Gnome instead of unity. I'm sure the problem is noveau isn't enough to enable 3D acceleration. And we have to install Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Before that we also have to remove noveau drivers. this is my knowledge base. No I want to know the detailed steps for the above

Can any one help?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried running the additional drivers tool in the menu? This will fetch the right drivers and do what you need. If that doesn't work please update your question with what happened.

[image]

Comment: I din't done it. But from some of the threads in ubuntforums I get to know that it will not work. So that I am asking for detailed steps to remove nveau and install proprietry driver

Comment: @Amax As you don't post your sources, it is hard to verify if they used the Additional Drivers installer or if they did it manually. If you use the Additional Drivers installer as suggested, Nouveau will be blacklisted from the kernel module prober. However, if you install it manually, you need to create a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` that contains `blacklist nouveau`.

Comment: I got Unity after installing the driver as Jorge Castro suggested. Thanks

Comment: @Amax please accept this answer as accepted (by clicking on the checkmark) if it's the answer, that way it doesn't show up as unanswered, thanks!